# Accessing a range of value in Python's tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I have the following tuple:

```
tuple = (65,67,5,67,34,76,67,231,98,67)
```

When I did the following:

```
print tuple3[2:8]
```

I got:

```
(5, 67, 34, 76, 67, 231)
```

I thought that `98` should be also included. Isn't `98` on the index number 8? Why isn't `98` included?

Thanks.

Comment: Slicing is [included:excluded]. This allows for things like `slicable[i:len(sliceable)]`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: Why the downvotes? Question is well formulated and answerable. It's quite clearly a dupe as noted above, but not a bad question *per se*.

Comment: @Tibo: NMDV, but one DV criterion is "does not show any research effort", and every tutorial on Python's slice notation explains this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a tuple or list - `x[start:end]`, slicing in python begins at `start` and runs till `end-1`.

That is the reason 98 is not included in your code